# How to add variables and default values to arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am facing difficulties in identifying the proper way to add the selected colors of cars into an arraylist. I am having an arraylist which is:

```
private List<String> selectedCars = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And one more for the carColors:

```
private List<String> carColors = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The selectedCars arraylist will store the selected cars ['TOYOTA','MAZDA','NISSAN'] as per the selection from the user.For certain cars, there is one default color which is 'Black', however for some of them, the user can select different colors.(ex. if 'Toyota', the user can select blue or red). Below is my code:

```
String carColor="";
String toyotaColor=""; // The value will be retrieved from the form once the user selected the color

if (selectedCars.contains("MAZDA"))
{
carColor="Black";
}
else if (selectedCars.contains("TOYOTA"))
{
carColor=toyotaColor;
}
else if (selectedCars.contains("NISSAN"))
{
carColor="Black";
}
else if (selectedCars.contains("FORD"))
{
carColor="Black";
}
```

Now my problem is that I want to pass the selected colors in a string array for each selected car in the selectedCars arraylist. In addition, I would like the separation between the colors should be ' ,' comma. so how can I do this?

In details, I need to store the carColors values in an arraylist for each selectedCars as the selected cars are : ['TOYOTA','MAZDA','NISSAN'] and I want to do the coding for an arraylist for the carColors which should be [toyotaColor,'Black','Black']

Thanks

Comment: This is a JDBC/Database question, no?

Comment: no it is related to arraylist

Comment: as is this is unclear, maybe you could add an example showing what you want

Comment: I have modified the code and provided an example of what I want exactly

Comment: You build a Car object and create a List<Car>.  The color goes in the Car object.  As far as the database, you have a row for each car type / car color combination.

Comment: Could you please assist in setting the carColors arraylist